# Google Bar Chart data.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, bar-chart

I tried to imply array to datatable that stores hours, value1 and value2. The array's length is 24. So, I need to use loop but I couldn't figure out where am I mistaking? Is this true logic for inserting data from array to datatable?

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Hours', 'Value1 Page Load Seconds', 'Value2 Page Load Seconds'] ]);



    for (var i=0; i<pageload.length;i++){
        data.push([pageload[i][0], pageload[i][1], pageload[i][2]]);
    }




    var options = {

        chart: {



            title: 'Hourly Page Load Times',

        },

            legend: { position: 'right' },
            axes: {
                x: {
                    0: { side: 'bottom', label: 'Hours'} // Top x-axis.
                }
            },
            bar: { groupWidth: "90%" },
            backgroundColor: {fill: 'transparent'},
            chartArea: {
                backgroundColor: 'transparent'

            }






    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart'));

    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't recommend using `arrayToDataTable` without all of the data.
because it determines the column types, based on the data.

instead, start with an array.

```
var data = [
    ['Hours', 'Value1 Page Load Seconds', 'Value2 Page Load Seconds']
];

for (var i=0; i<pageload.length;i++){
    data.push([pageload[i][0], pageload[i][1], pageload[i][2]]);
}

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);
```